# Formulario con HTML que guarde los datos en variables JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

necesito crear un formulario HTML que al momento de presionar submit, guarde todos los datos ingresados en diferentes variables, necesito que se guarden en esas variables para darles salida después por un documento .pdf el cual ya está programado.

A lo mejor parezca un poco tonta la pregunta, pero soy principiante. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es tonta la pregunta, pero hay muchos tutoriales que explican como hacer eso. Probablemente una busqueda en internet de unos cuantos minutos y algo de lectura te den las respuestas que necesitas. La comunidad se resiste a este tipo de preguntas por ser muy amplias y acaban cerradas.

Comment: Quiza agregando mas detalles puedas mejorar tu pregunta, y sobre todo. Si puedes agregar tu codigo actual, mas gente puede ayudarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes darle un `id` a los `inputs` y hacer lo sig:

```
function captutaDatos(){
var dato1 = document.getElementById('id_input').value
var dato2 = document.getElementById('id_input2').value
//...
}
```

y el form

```
<form onsubmit="capturaDatos(); return false">

</form>
```

Comment: no vote en contra, pero quiza sea porque `innerHTML` esta siempre vacio en elemento `<input>`, deberias usar `.value` en su lugar.

Comment: Por favor Kevin, procura contestar preguntas **bien formadas**, usa la guía [__*"Cómo escribo una buena respuesta"*__](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Puedes ayudar al autor a mejor su pregunta dirigiéndolo a esta guía _[ask]_.

Comment: si me habia confundido pero ya lo corregi

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido un montón.